# ED25519, RSA, Post Quantum Encryption confirmation

Tags: rsa, public-key, protocol-design, post-quantum-cryptography, kem

I am working on a chat feature to use both post quantum cryptography along with RSA, and want to confirm my thoughts.

As these algorithms haven't been fully battle tested, I have decided to use a combination of both PQE and usual public, secret key cryptography

I decided upon the best algorithms to use for security.

- Signing: ED25519
- PQE KEM: McEliece
- NON-PQE KEM: RSA 4096

We are currently using McEliece's uniformly distributed entropy as a shared secret, but generating an AES-GCM key for use with RSA 4096 public-secret cryptography.
I have decided upon ED25519, as no candidates have been chosen for Round 4 signing as of 05/2023.

My current thinking is the following

### Alice:

- Generate KEM keys
- Generate RSA keys
- Generate ED25519 keys
- Share public portions

### Bob:

- Generate KEM keys
- Generate RSA keys
- Generate ED25519 keys
- Share public portions

KEM

- Run encapsulation using Alice's KEM public key -> cipher text #1, shared secret #1 (256-bit uniform)

RSA

- Generate 256-bit AES-GCM key #2 (shared secret)
- Encrypt ss #2 AES-GCM key using Alice's RSA 4096 n,e public key -> cipher text #2

Message

- Message: "Hello world!"
- Encrypt message using shared secret #1 (256-bit uniform / aes key)
- Encrypt message using shared secret #2 (256-bit AES-GCM key)
- Sign double encrypted message using Bob's secret ED25519 signing key -> signature

Send

- Double encrypted message
- Double encrypted message signature
- KEM cipher text #1
- RSA cipher text #2

### Alice:

- Verify double encrypted message signature against Bob's public ED25519 Key
- Decapsulate KEM cipher text using Alice's secret KEM key -> shared secret #1
- Decapsulate RSA cipher text using Alice's secret RSA key -> shared secret #2
- Decrypt message using shared secret #2
- Decrypt message using shared secret #1
- "Hello world!"

My questions:

- Does the above look correct, or are there any changes you think would make sense?
- Is there an advantage to using RSA's encapsulate rather than encrypt?
- Should the message be encrypted twice as I assume, or does it make sense to encapsulate the cipher text output from one public-secret key cryptography algorithm?

Comment: Why not just generate the two AES keys and exclusive-or them together for the session key?

Comment: Just a side note. You say "no candidates have been chosen for Round 4 signing as of 05/2023.". NIST has already selected 3 signature algorithms (Dilithium, Falcon, SPHINCS+) that are going to be standardized and 1 KEM (Kyber) is also standardized. The 4th round is just to select an extra KEM based on a different hard problem than Kyber`s. NIST has also a parallel competition for digital signatures that was announced recently (and no submissions are public yet).
Also, you seem to generate KEM/RSA keys twice and using only one pair.

Comment: Look into https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ounsworth-cfrg-kem-combiners-03.html, you want to do a hybrid KEM -> derive one secret from the 2 shared secrets and then use it for AES encryption etc. (or to derive more keys)

Comment: @honzaik https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/pqc-dig-sig "there are no remaining digital signature candidates under consideration". Sorry for the confusion. Until new PQC signature algoritms are available, we will stick to non-PQC

Comment: Does it make sense to XOR the two keys? Would this reduce the space complexity?

Comment: XORing is not CCA-secure. See https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/024.pdf page 7. What do you mean by saving space complexity? The IETF draft is incomplete but afaik the proposal is basically to hash the shared secrets + ciphertexts therefore the output size is small (depends on the hash).